# Correct way to remove Bootstrap and install TailwindCSS in Laravel JetStream

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, tailwind-css, laravel-jetstream

I have a default Laravel project which is scaffold with Bootstrap and Vue.js.
Having considered to use Laravel JetStream Livewire, I am going to remove bootstrap because Laravel JetStreal Livewire is using TailwindCSS and we can not use both Bootstrap and TailwindCSS together.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.1",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.0",
    "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
}
```

I installed Bootstrap using `php artisan ui boostrap`.

Is there any standard way to remove bootstrap so that I can use only TailwindCSS in my project?

Answer (score 0):

bootsrtap only adds javascript and css files. So first remove the libraries bootsratp,jquery and popper.js. To remove bootsrtap run command:

```sh
npm uninstall bootstrap
```

then in *resources/js/bootstrap.js* remove:

```js
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

in *resources/sass/app.scss* remove:

```
// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

you can also delete file *resources/sass/_variables.scss*. Now run npm run dev/production.
you can also delete laravel/ui views if you've published them.
By doing these steps your laravel package will not depend on bootstrap, unless bootstrap is added by cdn somewhere.
Now you can add any other scaffolding you wish.